# Python Requests downloading File with Authentication

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to ping an API and download a file from a URL location. The calls I've made have been successful up until I try to actually download the file:

```
location = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/fuEleMy4ggfSfZRYGJjYdlymTisTvha2YjjnOcso'
r = requests.get(location,headers={'Authorization': u'XXXXXXXXX'})
```

The response:

```
{"response":{"status":"ERROR","error_code":"FORBIDDEN","errors":["Request a new token to download this file"]}}
```

The odd part is that the authorization token works for all the calls made to get to this point, but it always stops working at this step. There is little to no lag time between calls, and the token hasn't expired because I have tested other calls using it. I fear I am somehow passing in the authentication incorrectly with the Requests module.

Is there something different when downloading a file?

Comment: You need to use `sessions`  to download the file. May be I can answer in details if I could have the url

Comment: is sessions a python module?

Comment: I just tried doing this with sessions as well -- I'm able to make requests without having to pass in the header for each request, yet when I reach the download step, it still prompts me with the same error reply

Comment: Here's an example of the download location, although it is probably no longer "live": http://05.bm-data-api.prod.nym2.adnexus.net/siphon-download/sKPqUeagNjjl6ganFt9GkZCSg2EbHZV6RRiFdriM